# Get datatype of input variable in the command line Php

Tags: php, php-7, php-7.2

This is my code.

```
$fr = fopen("php://stdin", "r");
$input = fgets($fr);


if (preg_match('/^-?[0-9]{1,4}$/', $input)) {
    echo "Integer.";
} else if (preg_match('/^[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+$/', $input)) {
    echo "Float.";
} else if (preg_match('/[a-zA-Z\s]^[0-9]/', $input)) {
    echo "string.";
}
```

I will get the `$input` variable from the command line entered. I need to find what datatype the variable is either int, float, string.

Tried [gettype()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettype.php) method but it is always string. So only tried with `preg_match`.

Although in this also i am not getting the correct output.

Ex: 1.2e3 i am getting as string

Comment: Everything that comes from stdin is a string. Also, what is your question?

Comment: Do you know in advance what are the possible types you can receive?

Comment: For ex if the $input has only numbers then i need to find that the variable holds only integer. Suppose if it has float value then i need to check it is float

Comment: Use `ctype_` functions.

Answer (score 0):

All input from the command line (or any *pipe* for that matter) will always be a string, since no other types are supported. What you want to figure out is whether your string *is numeric* and then convert it to a number:

```
if (is_numeric($input)) {
    $input = +$input;
}
```

The unary `+` operator will cause the string to be interpreted as a number and result either in an `int` or `float`.